# Default description for UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, string-formatting

What is the numeric value in the default description of a UIViewController? I had expected it to be the instance address, or perhaps the hash, but when I tested this theory this is what I got:

```
NSLog(@"Self [%@]", self);
NSLog(@"Address [%p]", &self);
NSLog(@"Hash [%d]", [self hash]);

2012-09-26 10:28:00.202 QuickList7[85957:c07] Self [<SelectCategoryViewController: 0xa42fc60>]
2012-09-26 10:28:00.202 QuickList7[85957:c07] Address [0xbfffdea8]
2012-09-26 10:28:00.203 QuickList7[85957:c07] Hash [172162144]
```

I haven't been able to find an explanation in the reference for UIViewController or it's superclasses - anyone know?

Comment: In the second line you're getting the address of the pointer (i.e. pointer to pointer). Try passing `self` without ampersand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed the instance address, as for any other `description` implementations that use the `NSOBject`'s default implementation.

But the instance address is already in the `self` variable, as `self` is of type `UIViewController*` and is already a pointer. **Printing the pointer value of `&self` as you do in your example prints the address of the pointer (pointer to a pointer)**, not the address of the instance, as `&self` is indeed of type `UIViewController**`.

If you use `NSLog(@"%p", self)` instead of `NSLog(@"%p", &self)` you will see the same address printed as the one used by `description` and displayed with `NSLog(@"%@", self)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the instance address. In the second line, you are printing the address of the pointer to the instance (which is on the stack, and is why the address begins with `0xbfff`). Not the instance pointer itself. `NSLog(@"%p", self);` will show the same value as is displayed when you print `self` as an object with `%@`.